# PHP - Pregmatch for First three character is defined and 9 digit numeric

Tags: php

Kindly help on below `preg_match`.

1. MDR0123456789 - First three char should be **MDR** and 9 digit number.
2. MDR-OPX - Three character hypen three character.

Comment: You have ten digits in your first example.

Comment: ...and you really need to try something. SO isn't a free coding service where you just tell us what you want.

Comment: Please edit your question and try do consider these two things: 1.) There is no question in your question. What and where is your problem? 2.) What have you tried so far? Can you show us your regular expression? If you don't know the syntax for regulare expression, please do a little research on your own and ask a more specific question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^MDR[0-9]{9}$
^MDR\-[A-Za-z]{3}$
```